# How to avoid jumping html elements over each others

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, display

I'm new to CSS and web development and trying to build my own and first website. I've read a few articles related to displaying and positioning elements however I still unable to get elements positioned perfectly while resizing the browser window!.

What I am trying to accomplish is in the codepen link in the first comment below
https://codepen.io/letsimoo/pen/XWNGoGa

HTML CODE

```
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>


<body class="mainBody">
  <header class="mainHeader">

    <div class="headerStuff">

      <div class="social-list">

        <div class="fb">
          FB
        </div>

        <div class="twitter">
          Twitter
        </div>

        <div class="instagram">
          Instagram
        </div>

      </div>

      <ul class="navigation">
        
        <li> <a href=""> <b>My Projects</b> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href=""> <b>Gallery</b> </a> </li>

        <li> <a href=""> <b> About </b> </a> </li>

        <li> <a href=""> <b>Contact</b> </a> </li>

      </ul>

      <div class="logoDiv">
        <h2>Logo</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="HeaderLine"></div> <!-- Header Separator Line -->

  </header>

</body>
```

CSS CODE

```
    * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mainBody {
  background-color: gray;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}

.mainHeader {
  height: 80px;
}

.headerStuff {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: bottom;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-list {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: -10px;
}

.social-list div {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  right: 175px;
  text-align: right;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.navigation li {
  background-color: #22385b;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  color: white;
}

.navigation li:hover {
  background-color: #446291;
}

.navigation li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Chakra Petch", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

ul li .prayer-window {
  background-color: rgba(237, 239, 242, 0.9);
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px black;
  transition: 1s opacity, 5s width, 5s height;
}

.prayer-time:hover {
  color: hotpink;
}
.prayer-time:active ~ .prayer-window {
  opacity: 1;
}

.logoDiv {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

.logoDiv img {
  width: 150px;
}

.HeaderLine {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: 68px;
  margin-right: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black, 0 0 30px red, 0 0 5px darkblue;
}
```

Please have a look to my code in the above link and try to resize the browser window to the minimum size

**What the problem I'm facing?**
Definitely you've notices how is the navigation elements jumped over the social media dev after resizing the browser window

So how can avoid this ugly act from the headerStuff div!??

Also please help me to improve my question if there are something wrong in my description or in the mentioned tags

Comment: Using Bootstrap:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/ you can easily make website responsive, this can solve your problem easily

Comment: @Satish Modha what I'm doing is a simle page... using bootstrap is going to make me rebuild my page from the begaining in addition to read a huge documrntation to understand how it works and to memorise classes names which is wasting the time for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.navigation` `.sosial-list` are positioned `absolute`. That means they are out of the order of the other elements and does not take space by the other content.

As absolute positioned element `.navigation` is allways relative to the next parent element which is not positioned static. In your project it is `.header-stuff`. At the same time the `margin-top` moves it down from the top edge of header-stuff ...

So, if the screen becomes narrow your `.header-stuff` becomes narrow also. And your navigation keeps still in place: `175px` from right edge of `.header stuff` and `30px`margin from top ... that make it layered above your socials.

If you want to keep your structure enlarge the `margin-top` for `.navigation` so the navigation has still place enough to move below the social information.

But if you are open to change your sturcture you don't need an absolute positioning. Use a structure with block elements so socials and navigations are still beneath and don't layer over each other.

Just easy DEMO code structure example to explain the idea:

```
// css structure DEMO


nav { 
   display: block; 
}

ul {
   /* align ul to right */
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: auto;
}

li {
   /* align li's into a line */
   display: inline-block;
}

header hr {
   ... style your subheader line ...
}


// html structure DEMO
<header>

   <div class="top-header>
      ... your socials ...
   </div>

   <nav>

      <ul>

         <li></li>
         ...

      </ul>
      
   </nav>

   <hr>

</header>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation now I understand where my fault was.
your notes helped me to solve the problem =)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your updated updated CSS:

```
* {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
.mainBody {
   background-color: gray;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   color: white;
   /* margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px; */
 }
.headerStuff {
   height: 80px;
   display: flex;
   position: relative;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   width: 100%;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
 }
.social-list {
   display: inline-flex;
 }
.social-list div {
   margin-left: 12px;
 }
.navigation {
   margin: 0;
 }
.navigation li {
   background-color: #22385b;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   font-size: 20px;
   width: 90px;
   color: white;
 }
.navigation li:hover {
   background-color: #446291;
 }
.navigation li a {
   color: white;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
 }
ul li .prayer-window {
   background-color: rgba(237, 239, 242, 0.9);
   margin-top: 20px;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 0;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px black;
   transition: 1s opacity, 5s width, 5s height;
 }
.prayer-time:hover {
   color: hotpink;
 }
.prayer-time:active ~ .prayer-window {
   opacity: 1;
 }
.logoDiv h2 {
   margin: 0;
}
.logoDiv img {
   width: 150px;
 }
.HeaderLine {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 2px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: pink;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black, 0 0 30px red, 0 0 5px darkblue;
 }
```

You can adjust css properties for specific screen sizes via media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 796px) {
   //
}
```

PS. `align-items:bottom` is not really a thing. Probably you meant `align-items:baseline`